# jquery ajax how to determine a server process is running or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Project Type: ASP.NET 3.5
Language : C#

One of page uses Ajax Timer on page load.So while execution start, I start the timer using

```
this.AjaxTimer.Enabled = true;
```

This is used to start execution of a time consuming code like,

```
protected void AjaxTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Disable the Ajax Timer, so that it won't execute again after 500 ms
    this.AjaxTimer.Enabled = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < 140000; i++)
    {
     // Code here
    }
}
```

How do I know whether the process is completed or running when I close the browser window using jQuery ?

**OR**

Simply, how can I know whether a server process is executing when I close the browser window? If it is running I want to abort it.

**OR**

How can I do the following stuff with jQuery

Script :

```
function abortRequest() {
    var obj = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (obj.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        obj.abortPostBack();
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<body style="background-color: Gray;" onunload="abortRequest();">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the same code to test the whether server side script is running or not. But you may write the code inside document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    if (obj.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
        obj.abortPostBack();
    }
});
```